# Interpreting the logistic model intercept

Tags: regression, logistic

I have fitted the logistic model that has coefficient of age and level of income. The dataset has values for age 18-60 so my thinking is that since we cannot set age to 0, interpreting the intercept will not make sense. Am I thinking right?

Comment: Since age is 18-60, you can use `Age-18` variable in your model. Then intercept would be interpreted as outcome for person who is 18 y.o.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly.

Interpreting the intercept in *any* model only makes sense if a setting of zero for all predictors (and the reference level for factor predictors) makes sense. And setting age to zero for a model for income obviously doesn't.

(I don't know whether discretizing income, which is a continuous variable, and using a logistic model makes a lot of sense, either.)